# what is %s and %d?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am trying to learn iOs programming. and I suppose this is a bit of a reverse question.

I have just completed a tutorial on youtube using Xcode to create a simple iPhone app that will allow you to store, list and delete data from an SQLite3 database (as the app i want to produce will need a database).

However the bloke who put the video up didn't seem to explain 'why' he did what he did, so I am now trying to understand what each bit of code does
(I come from a PHP and SQL web programming background, so I understand accessing databases, calling data rows etc to show the content on a website.)

The one part of this iOs bit I don't quite understand is the %s and %d values used as they didn't seem to be declared anywhere.

The code is;

```
if(sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &personDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *inserStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PERSONS(NAME,AGE) values ('%s', '%d')",[self.nameField.text UTF8String],[self.ageField.text intValue]];
```

now %s and %d clearly get their values from the self.nameField and self.ageField. However that implies that I could only ever submit two values into a table? or are there other % for other values, but surely then there is a max of 26.

I would be grateful for any explanation you could give.

Also in addition, does anyone have any suggestions about other fully explained ways to learn to code for iOS? especially if you were a starter just learning iOS programming for a first time with limited C programming skills before hand.
The area i am looking for is to create an app that will store some text fields and an image, which either will be stored in a database and the image either in the database or as a link and appropriately named.
I'd like to be able to manipulate the image to resize it so it is optimised for the iPhone display (don't need a HD image in the APP)
Later I'd like to be able to work out how either upload the local database (sqlite3) file to a  an online storage (either my own server or dropbox), or synchronise it to an SQL database (from initial looks just exporting the file would be better and embedding the images into a field would be better for this project, even though i know it is not the normal way of doing things)

Comment: `%s` and `%d` aren't variables, but how to treat the inputs to format them properly.

Comment: Start with the documentation for [NSString#stringWithFormat:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:)

Comment: Also, keep your questions simple - avoid writing "multipart" questions. This one rambles on about oh so many things.

Comment: On a side note, never use a string format to create a query. Use ? for the variables and then use the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions to fill in the values. The INSERT statement you posted is wrong because numbers don't go in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` and `%d` are format specifiers for a null-terminated array of characters and a signed 32-bit integer respectively. You can find the details about specifiers in the [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1). However, you should not format the string this way for a SQLite statement as it puts you at risk of SQL injection. Instead you should [bind the values](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) using `?` and the appropriate `sqlite3_bind*` function. For your situation you would use `sqlite3_bind_text` for `NAME` and `sqlite3_bind_int` for `AGE`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the class reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Here are the string format specifiers:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265

As you can see, `%d` is outputting an integer while `%s` is outputting a string.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1:

The % convention "string format specifiers" is a common standard for string substitution.

They are not variables, but typed substitution placeholders.

```
%s --> string
%d --> number
```

Part 2:
You might check out the iTunes U course:

iPhone Application Programming '11
by Prof. Jan Borchers

https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/iphone-application-programming/id474416629

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

**%s**
Null-terminated array of 8-bit unsigned characters. Because the %s specifier causes the characters to be interpreted in the system default encoding, the results can be variable, especially with right-to-left languages. For example, with RTL, %s inserts direction markers when the characters are not strongly directional. For this reason, it’s best to avoid %s and specify encodings explicitly.

**%d, %D**
Signed 32-bit integer (int).

Answer (score 0):

That is what is called a formatted string, basically, it is a way to inject values into a string.  The character after the % sign is used to indicate the datatype that the value should be formatted as.  In your case, %s is used to indicate a string value and %d is used to indicate a decimal integral value.

This type of string formatting is extremely common; many programming languages provide some mechanism for performing this type of string formatting and the formatting symbols are largely standardized.  You can find a more information [on the C++ website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).